# How to check if QProcess is executing correctly?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

```
QProcess process_sdcompare;
QString command_sdcompare;
QStringList args_sdcompare;

command_sdcompare = "diff";
args_sdcompare << "Filename" << "Filename";

process_sdcompare.start(command_sdcompare,args_sdcompare,QIODevice::ReadOnly);
process_sdcompare.waitForFinished();                                        
QString StdOut_sdcompare = process_sdcompare.readAllStandardOutput(); //Reads standard output
QString StdError_sdcompare = process_sdcompare.readAllStandardError(); //Reads standard error

if(StdOut_sdcompare.isEmpty())  //the process output is checked here if empty it is a success
    return 1;
```

I am running the above code. When I check for an error condition after comparing not similar text files, `isEmpty()` returns `false`.

How do I check if the `QProcess` execution occurred without errors?

Comment: Just a comment, which has nothing to do with your problem: your comments in the code are quite useless. They are just the names of the called functions with spaces between the words. It's better to comment why something was written the way it is, not what is happening in the line, as this should be clear from the code.

Comment: Regarding your question: You should look at the [exit code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#exitCode) of the process

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use `QProcess::error()` to query the last error (for quick debugging), however a "nicer" way to do it:

```
// capture any errors (do this before you run the process)
connect(&process_sdcompare, &QProcess::errorOccurred, this, &ThisClass::processError);
```

Then define slot:

```
ThisClass::processError(QProcess::ProcessError error)
{
    qDebug() << "error enum val = " << error << endl;
}
```

**update**

Or with Lambda:

```
// No need to define a slot function...
connect(&process_sdcompare, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [=](QProcess::ProcessError error) 
{ 
    qDebug() << "error enum val = " << error << endl; 
});
```

Comment: The code could be tidier, in my opinion, if you connect to a lambda function (Qt 5) instead of having to define the slot, but other than that, yes it's the way to go ;O)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight ehhh...ok forcing me to write a lambda : ) , my lambda defs are still a bit ropey so please cast your eye over it to check its ok (I have not got a dev PC nearby today)

Answer (score 3):

I think all the status and error functions are pretty useless to figure out if the process execution was actually successful. Example, trying to execute a program which does not exist (under windows):

```
error(): QProcess::ProcessError(FailedToStart)
exitStatus(): QProcess::ExitStatus(NormalExit)
exitCode(): 0
errorString(): "Process failed to start: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden."
```

If the process was actually executed successfully:

```
error(): QProcess::ProcessError(UnknownError)
exitStatus(): QProcess::ExitStatus(NormalExit)
exitCode(): 0
errorString(): "Unknown error"
```

So I would consider "Unknown error" not an indicator for success.

The solution I think could look like this:

```
QProcess *m_proc = new QProcess(this);
bool errorOccured = false;
QProcess::ProcessError procError;
QObject::connect(m_proc, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [&](QProcess::ProcessError error)
{
    procError = error;
    errorOccured = true;
});

m_proc->start(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

When [`waitForFinished`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished) returns, it returns a `bool` that broadly indicates success. As Karsten recommended, you can then check for actual success or failure using [`QProcess::exitCode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#exitCode).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use `QProcess`

```
QProcess process_sdcompare;
QStringList args_sdcompare;
args_sdcompare << "Filename" << "Filename";    
process_sdcompare.setProgram("diff");
process_sdcompare.setArguments(args_sdcompare);
process_sdcompare.start();
if (process_sdcompare.waitForStarted() && process_sdcompare.waitForFinished()) {
  QString StdOut_sdcompare = process_sdcompare.readAllStandardOutput();   
  QString StdError_sdcompare = process_sdcompare.readAllStandardError();

  if(StdOut_sdcompare.isEmpty())
      return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Its a good code example : ) - but I don't think it really answers the users question (how to check QProcess execution for errors)