# Asynchronous check if QProcess started correctly

Tags: qt, qt5, qprocess

I need to check if the process **started** correcly.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37962783/9432646) on the 
similar question, however mine is a bit different.

#### Synchronous

For synchronous check I could easily do something like this:

```
QProcess process("foo.exe");
if (!process.waitForStarted()) {
    qWarning() << process.errorString();
}
```

#### Asynchronous

For asynchronous check I could do this:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess("foo.exe");
connect(process, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [=]() { 
    qWarning() << process->errorString();
});
```

However, the [`QProcess::errorOccurred`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#errorOccurred) was introduced only in Qt 5.6.

#### Question

So how do I perform an **asynchronous** check if the `QProcess` started correctly in **Qt < 5.6**?

Comment: The `QProcess::errorOccurred` is basically the same as  `QProcess::error`. So why is yours different? If you explain it, i will modify or delete my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation there is a signal [QProcess::error](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qprocess.html#error-1) in Qt 5.5 and earlier.

> This signal is emitted when an error occurs with the process. The
>   specified error describes the type of error that occurred.

No, the `QProcess::error` is what you need. It contains all [information](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qprocess.html#ProcessError-enum) to check if an error occurred.

```
QProcess::FailedToStart 0   The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.
QProcess::Crashed   1   The process crashed some time after starting successfully.
QProcess::Timedout  2   The last waitFor...() function timed out. The state of QProcess is unchanged, and you can try calling waitFor...() again.
QProcess::WriteError    4   An error occurred when attempting to write to the process. For example, the process may not be running, or it may have closed its input channel.
QProcess::ReadError 3   An error occurred when attempting to read from the process. For example, the process may not be running.
QProcess::UnknownError  5   An unknown error occurred. This is the default return value of error().
```

**Asynchronous check, Qt 5.5 and earlier**

```
connect(process, static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(QProcess::ProcessError)>(&QProcess::error),
    [=](QProcess::ProcessError error){ if(error == QProcess::FailedToStart) qDebug() << "Process failed to start"; });
```

`QProcess::error` does exactly what you need.